# How to determine if a Markov chain converge to equilibrium?

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

For example, if there is a matrix$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.3 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
the stationary distribution is when $\pi_2$ = 1.07692$\pi_1$,$\pi_3$ = 1.53846$\pi_1$,$\pi_4$ = 0.53846$\pi_1$

So the stationary distribution exists. 
Does it mean that the matrix converges to equilibrium?

I am learning this chapter on my own and I am quite confusing ... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Markov chain converges to a unique equilibrium if there is only one recurrent class and it is aperiodic.  In this case the directed graph corresponding to the Markov chain looks like this:

[image]

The Markov chain is irreducible (i.e. every state communicates with every other state), but it is periodic with period $2$, because from states $1$ and $2$ you can only go to $3$ and $4$ and vice versa.  Therefore it does not converge to an equilibrium.  In fact, the even powers of the matrix converge to
$$ \frac{1}{27} \pmatrix{13 & 14 & 0 & 0\cr
                         13 & 14 & 0 & 0\cr 
                          0 & 0 & 20 & 7\cr
                          0 & 0 & 20 & 7\cr}$$
and the odd powers converge to
$$ \frac{1}{27} \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 20 & 7\cr
                         0 & 0 & 20 & 7\cr
                        13 & 14 & 0 & 0\cr
                        13 & 14 & 0 & 0\cr}$$